# Hashmap value storage if it exceeds integer range

Tags: hashmap, integer-overflow

As many of us know that initially `HashMap` allocates a memory with default initial capacity of 16 and the default load factor of 0.75. Now when we try to store values into `HashMap`first it calculates bucket location by calling hashcode function on hash map key. Suppose if user defined `hashcode` methods returns a value which is greater than integer range and that values exceeds initial capacity address of `HashMap`, then how the value will get stored in `HashMap`?

or

As hashcode method can return any value within in integer range then how JVM knows that it has to store hash map value within that initially allocated memory location?

Comment: As hashcode method can return any value within in integer range then how JVM knows that it has to store hash map value within that initially allocated memory location? For example when we create hash map it creates an array of size 16 slots.when we try to store value to hash map it gets stored within this array.So How JVM knows it has to store within this arrays as hashcode function can return address value greater than array address size.

Comment: Your question is very confusingly written.

Answer (score 0):

`Hash Map` can have pairs up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, After exceeding that limit it will cause for some methods unexpected behavior such as `size()`, but it will not effect to the methods such as `remove()`, `get()` and `put()` Because `remove()` removes the mapping for the specified key from this map if present and  `get()` returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key. And `put()` associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced. How ever there can be collision between new object with an existing object.

Refference - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: As hashcode method can return any value within in integer range then how JVM knows that it has to store hash map value within that initially allocated memory location?

Answer (score 0):

The index of the bucket to store an object in is computed from the result of `hashCode`, but is rarely actually equal to it.

e.g. if you use a power-of-two number of buckets, a common approach is

```
bucketIndex = key.hashCode() & (numberOfBuckets - 1);
```

I don't know what precise method `HashMap` uses to compute the bucket index.

Comment: Thanks for you response.As you said index of the bucket to store an object in is computed from the result of hashCode.But what If hashcode returns a value where bucket Index might go out of range of allocated memory.

Comment: @user3309975: Then you didn't do a very good job choosing the function for computing the bucket index,